# superset flask fab create-admin not working

Tags: python, apache-superset

I have installed superset using `pip install apache-superset` command.
Then I try to flask fab create-admin but it's saying:

> Error: Could not import "superset.superset"

Can anyone help me here?

```
(superset) D:\dev\python\python_vir_env\superset\Lib\site-packages\superset>set FLASK_APP=superset
(superset) D:\dev\python\python_vir_env\superset\Lib\site-packages\superset>flask fab create-admin

Username [admin]: admin
User first name [admin]: jvcson
User last name [user]: pam
Email [admin@fab.org]: 123@qq.com
Password:
Repeat for confirmation:

2020-04-14 15:06:21,254:INFO:root:logging was configured successfully
2020-04-14 15:06:21,419:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>

Usage: flask fab create-admin [OPTIONS]
Error: Could not import "superset.superset".
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has fixd,running

```
python superset fab create-admin'at path '...\site-packages\superset\bin
```

[image]